# how can I show changes in X on its own even though it is HEAVILY influenced by Y?

Tags: statistics, economics

I am so out of my depth I don't even know how to ask the question properly, really looking for an "ELI5" to show me where to start looking...

Over time, X grows. It's influenced by many things, but the most important thing is Y.

is it possible to project X's growth *without* the influence of Y?

Made up numbers:

```
2020:
x = 300
y = 400

2021:
x = 750
y = 930

2022:
x = 325
y = 600

2023:
x = 375
y = 500
```

... obviously in 2021 things jumped a lot due to Y.  but there would have been an increase anyway...

Comment: Linear regression?

Comment: @Aruralreader  thanks I will google and see what I can figure out!

Comment: @Aruralreader  for the purposes of my question, I think your comment should be the "answer".  I think this is what I'm after.. of course I'll likely have to post another question in the near future -- high school math did not prepare me for this, especially given it was 25 years ago lol